# Список языков в ISO3 android

Tags: java, android, locale

Подскажите как узнать код языка в `ISO3`, и где собственно найти весь список языков. Мне необходимо это для того, чтобы пользователь сам выбирал язык внутри приложения. (список должен содержать 3-х буквенные значения языка: rus, eng, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
 for(Locale locale:locales) {
    //локаль на человеческом языке
    Log.i(TAG, "Language: "+locale.getDisplayLanguage());
    //локаль в ISO3
    Log.i(TAG, "ISO 3 language: "+locale.getISO3Language());
    //страна в ISO3
    Log.i(TAG, "ISO 3 country: "+locale.getISO3Country());
 }
```